# Using port forwarding to send UDP packets across devices

Tags: port-forwarding

I have 3 Linux devices connected to each other as shown. Devices A and B are embedded computers running Yocto. Device C is a Ubuntu PC. The network is entirely self-contained (no external connections to the internet or anything else).

[image]

An application on Device A is sending UDP packets on port 14550 that I want Device C to receive. Because of some nuances of this application, I have A sending the UDP packets to 192.168.22.102 (instead of 10.1.1.10). No problem: I added a route on Device A.

```
#Device A
ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 10.1.1.10 dev wlan0-ap
```

I verified the route works because I can ping B's eth0 interface from A.

Next, I set up port forwarding on B so it can hand off the UDP packets to C on the same port 14550:

```
#Device B
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/forwarding
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -i wlan0 --dport 14550 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.22.7:14550
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 192.168.22.7 --dport 14550 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

and opened up port 14550 for incoming and outgoing.

```
#Device B
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 14550 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 14550 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Here is the output of `iptables -S` on Device B:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 14550 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.22.7/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 14550 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 14550 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Lastly, I allowed incoming UDP packets on port 14550 on Device C using gufw.

Alas, none of the UDP packets are showing up on Device C. Is there a fundamental step I'm missing? What troubleshooting steps should I try? Please keep in mind that Devices A and B are running BusyBox versions of many of the basic networking applications, so I'll be a little limited in what I can and can't do.